# Help in this little doubt in this proof from Hoffman and Kunze's Linear Algebra book

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, proof-explanation

I'm reading [Hoffman and Kunze's Linear Algebra book](http://uap.unnes.ac.id/ebook/mathematics%20ebook/Algebra/Linear%20Algebra,%202nd%20ed%20-%20Kenneth%20Hoffman,%20Ray%20Kunze,%201971.pdf) and on page 177 they stated and proved the following theorem:

[image]

It's a big proof which I didn't understand only a very little part of it:

[image]
[image]
[image]

I tried a lot but I couldn't understand why $\sigma_2^{-1}\gamma\sigma_1^{-1}\in G(r+s,t)$.

I think this fact is not from advanced group theory and we need only a basic knowledge of abstract algebra to prove this. Therefore I'm almost sure I missed something silly or the authors made a mistake in this proof.

I need help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is straight from definitions.

- The $\sigma$s by definition leave the members of the index set $I_t=\{r+s+1,\ldots,r+s+t\}$ invariant and $\gamma$ by definition permute the members of $I_t$ among themselves. Therefore $\sigma_2\gamma\sigma_1^{-1}$ permute the members of $I_t$ among themselves.
- Similarly, by definition, the $\sigma$s and $\gamma$ permute the members of the index set $I_{rs}=\{1,2,\ldots,r+s\}$ among themselves. Therefore $\sigma_2\gamma\sigma_1^{-1}$ also permute the members of $I_{rs}$ among themselves.
- So, in summary, $\sigma_2\gamma\sigma_1^{-1}$ permute the members of $I_{rs}$ among themselves and it also permute the members of $I_t$ among themselves. Now that's exactly what a permutation in $G(r+s,t)$ means.

Comment: Why is the $\gamma$ an identity on $I_{rs}$? thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: @user42912 Sorry, that was wrong. $\gamma$ by definition is in $G(r,s,t)$. It isn't an identity on $I_{rs}$. Nonetheless it permutes the members of $I_{rs}$ among themselves. This is now fixed in the answer.